# laravel factory model not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-seeding

im trying to create a new project with everything to know more about laravel, for now im creating models, migrations and seeds with factory and im running into this problem:

Model User

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{

  protected $table = 'user'; //name of the table in database
  protected $primaryKey = 'Id'; //Primary Key of the table

  /**
   * Relations between tables
   */
   public function GetLoginInfo()
   {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Models\LoginInfo', 'UserId');
   }

   public function getStatus()
   {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\AccountStatus');
   }

}
```

Model Account status

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AccountStatus extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'account_status'; //name of the table in database
  protected $primaryKey = 'Id'; //primary Key of the table
  public $timestamps = false; //true if this table have timestaps
  /**
   * Relations between tables
   */
   public function GetUsers()
   {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Users', 'StatusId');
   }
}
```

Seed file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UserSeeder extends Seeder
{
  /**
   * Run the database seeds.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function run()
  {
    factory(App\Models\User::class, 5)->create();
  }
}
```

factory file:

```
<?php
/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

//Factory for Account Status table
$factory->define(App\Models\AccountStatus::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
      'Description' => $faker->word,
    ];
});

//Factory for user table
$factory->define(App\Models\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
      'Username' => $faker->unique()->userName,
      'Password' => bcrypt('test'),
      'Email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
      'Name' => $faker->name,
      'StatusId' => Factory(App\Models\AccountStatus::class)->create()->id,
    ];
});
```

when trying to db seed with artisan:

```
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Class 'App\Models\Model' not found
```

already trying composer dump-autoload , optimize and i have the models in a folder in App\Models.

the seeds with factory for the account status work, but when i try to run for both (account status then user) i have that error) anyone knows why?
and is good practice to have all the factory code in 1 file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `User` Model you are extending `Model` class whereas you should extend `Authenticatable` class alias.

So your `User` model will look as:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
```

Comment: worked, so the authenticatable already is a model? 

another question how can i add a foreign key from other table information ? this dont work: 'StatusId' => Factory(App\Models\AccountStatus::class)->create()->id

Comment: Yes, `authenticatable` is a model but also remember that it's only alias of `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`. And for your second question, I am not sure about the solution but you can answer another question for that.